# jQuery search and replace part of img src

Tags: javascript, jquery

On every page I have a featured image that has an image like this:

```
<img class="js-image-replace" src="http://www.example.com/category_name/320/89645428_89645427.jpg" />
```

The `/320/` is referencing the size of the image, and I want it to be `/660/`

How would I search for the 320 and replace it with 660?

All my attempts overwrite the entire string.

Comment: Why you don't use **search and replace** in your IDE?

Comment: Please show your attempts and let us know what specifically goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can guarantee that this value would be the first set of integers that you would encounter within the string, then you could use the following expression to replace it :

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $('.js-image-replace').each(function(){
      // Get your image src
      var source = $(this).attr('src');
      // Replace the first set of integers in your URL with 660
      $(this).attr('src',source.replace(/\/\d+\//,'/660/'));
  });
})
</script>
```

Otherwise,

**Example**

You can [see a working example of this in action here](http://jsbin.com/bazitat/1/edit?html,console) and output below :

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This works! Except for categories that have an integer in their name. The one thing I can guarantee, is that the structure is always the same. example.com/category_name/320/blabla.png
Meaning that the ```/320/``` is always the second directory.

Comment: I updated the expression to match the slashes as well and just added those to the replacement string. It should work even with numerical categories now.

Comment: @RionWilliams yep you are correct - comment deleted

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm. Thank you so much!